# How to make your own IO function in C?

Tags: c, string, io

I want to know what is the code to write a getchar() function by your own.

Comment: `int getchar() { return fgetc(stdin); }` ^^. Do you speak about driver ?

Comment: No I just want to input characters from keyboard without using getchar or ... I want to write my own getchar function but I dont know how.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is too broad a question and is indeed off-topic for this site.

Comment: what is your system? micro-controller? PC? Mac?  How far do you want to go: registers, low layer driver,  high layer driver?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use other library functions (like fgetc), you have to use the system calls provided by the operating system.

For Unix systems (Linux, macOS etc.) for example you have to use `ssize_t read (int fd, void* buf, size_t cnt)` for input and `ssize_t write (int fd, const void* buf, size_t cnt)` for output. In Windows you have almost identical functions (`_read` and `_write`).

Comment: @AsHkaN there is no level difference between the _fgetc_ I put in remark and these _read/write_ functions ... nor with _getchar_. These _read/write are standard library functions

Comment: @bruno: there are major differences between the `FILE *` file stream based I/O and the `int` file descriptor based I/O, and since the stream I/O is usually implemented using the descriptor I/O, it is not unreasonable to interpret the stream I/O as being at a higher level than the descriptor I/O.  It is not mandated that they're implemented like that.  Nevertheless, practically 50 years of Unix history says "that's the way it is" (even if it is not legislated by the standards).  Also, the C standard mandates stream I/O; POSIX adds descriptor I/O — different standards, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler to use read/write is not _make my own IO function_, this is what I said

Comment: We're going to have to agree to disagree on the meaning of terminology, then, @bruno.  -oo-

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this is a recurrent problem with the human languages ^^ Perhaps we can agree on the fact the OP's question is unclear ;-)